# запуск bat скрипта cmd с правами администратора

Tags: bat, права

Всем привет
Есть bat скрипт на автоматическое подключение к впн/команду route add/подключение дисков с серверной.
Всё бы ничего, да только команда route add должна выполняться через cmd с правами администратора.
Вопрос, как можно выполнить bat скрипт, чтобы он открылся не в обычной cmd, а с правами администратора ?

Comment: Руками - по правой кнопке мышки. Можно задание повесить и там поставить галочку "выполнять с наивысшими привилегиями"

Answer (score 0):

Это делается с помощью runas.

```
runas /user:Administrator "cmd /k {fullpath}\file.bat"
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось только создав ярлык к этому батнику.

Заходите в свойство ярлыка, переходите на вкладку «Ярлык», кнопка «Дополнительно…», в появившемся окне ставите галочку «Запуск от имени администратора». После этого стандартным действием для ярлыка (выполняемым по двойному клику, и отмеченное жирным шрифтом в контекстном меню) будет не «Открыть», а «Запустить от имени администратора».

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811372/how-to-code-a-bat-file-to-always-run-as-admin-mode